# How to pass row id into a functon onclick button, bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap 4 and trying to build a bootstrap table with delete/edit buttons. I used ajax to load the data into table. My problem is, when I click on delete or edit button, it doesn't pass row id(row.id) to function. I tested it with alert and shows 'undefined'. The same code I previously used for another bootstrap table and it works fine. I could not see any wrong here but it's not working. I kindly expect your help.

HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="expenseTable"      
       data-search="true"
       data-pagination="true">
     <thead class="table-light">
         <tr>
            <th scope="col" data-feild="id" data-sortable="true">Id</th>
            <th scope="col" data-feild="user" data-sortable="true">User</th>
            <th scope="col" data-feild="category" data-sortable="true">Category</th>
            <th scope="col" data-feild="source" data-sortable="true">Source</th>
            <th scope="col" data-feild="description" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
            <th scope="col" data-feild="amount" data-sortable="true">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col" data-feild="date" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="expenseTblBdy">
                                                
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    load();

    function loadExpenseData(data){
         $(function() {
             $('#expenseTable').bootstrapTable({
                  data: data,
                  columns: [ {},{},{},{},{},{},{},  
                  {
                    field: 'operate',
                    title: 'Action',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    clickToSelect: false,
                    formatter : function(value,row,index) {
    
                         return '<button class=\'btn btn-primary btn-sm btnExp-up\' pageName="'+row.id+'" pageDetails="'+row.user+'">Update</button> <button class=\'btn btn-danger btn-sm btnExp-del\' pageName="'+row.id+'">Dalete</button>';
                          }
                        }
                      ]              
                });
    
    
                $(".btnExp-up").click(function(e){
                    
                    var expId = $(this).attr('pageName');
                    alert(expId);
    
                    //modifyExp(expId);
                    // $("#mdlOutsideUpdate").modal("show");
    
                     e.stopPropagation();
                });
    
                $(".btnExp-del").click(function(e){
                    
                    var expId = $(this).attr('pageName');
    
                    removeExp(expId);
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    
                });
    
            });
        }

});
```

what load function do is load data into table using ajax and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert `pageName` and `pageDetails` into `data-*` attribute. The return function will look something like

```
return 
`
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnExp-up" data-pageName="${row.id}" data-pageDetails="${row.user}> 
     Update
   </button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnExp-del" data-pageName="${row.id}">
     Delete
   </button>
`;
```

Then in the button-click events, you access the data-values like

```
var expId = $(this).data('pageName');
```

NOTE: I've not tried it, but I hope it works.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but did not work. Anyway I'm so grateful for your help.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console before or after clicking on the button?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply and the error was fixed by changing the database column name which used to store 'id'. Thank You.